# Convert month(name) year to date in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My date column has values like

```
Date
1971 FEB
1971 MAR
.
.
```

How to convert this into YYYY-MM-DD format?

This is what I tried

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] , format='%y%b')
```

but I get an error message

```
ValueError: time data '1971 FEB' does not match format '%y%b' (match)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with format `'%Y %b'` instead of `'%y%b'`:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y %b',errors='coerce')
```

For more info regarding format codes [visit here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)